# Visual Studio Code debugging PHP and logging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug, monolog

I am debugging server side PHP code in Visual Studio Code with PHP Debug -extension and Xdebug.

I am also using Monolog as a logger for my project.

Is it possible to print Monolog logs into VSCode Debug Console? I would like to see the outputs while I am doing debugging.

Comment: I too am interested in this. Did you find anything of use?